# What's a VPS "looking glass"?

Tags: vps

I see this term tossed around everywhere VPS are discussed, but I can't seem to find a definition and I have no idea what it might mean!

What's a "looking glass" in relation to virtual private server hosting?

Answer (score 2):

A Looking Glass enables you to run network diagnostic tests from one of the VPS host's servers. Basically it's a way for them to let you run `traceroute`, `ping`, etc as if you were SSH'd into their server.

For example, if you care about latency, you might run some ping tests from different hosts' Looking Glass servers to see which has the lowest ping times to a particular IP.

VPS hosts vary widely in quality, so it's worth running a few `traceroute` commands before signing up to check what kind of network they're on.

I've also used them before when a website visitor was having issues reaching my server. I wasn't sure if it was a network issue between the visitor and my host, or a firewall issue on my server, so I ran some network tests from the host's looking glass to the visitor's IP.

There's also a Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Looking_Glass_server